# Keep black status bar in legacy project

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

I got an "old project", and modified it for supporting iOS8. 
In the app status bar has black color.

I set `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `NO` and status bar style to black opaque one in `Info.plist`.

Here is the part of `AppDelegate.m` file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {
      application.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
    }

    application.statusBarHidden = NO;

   UIImage *navBarImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation-bar"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 9, 0, 9)];

   [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBarImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

So I expected to have on all controllers, black status bar with white color.

It works in most of the cases. But when I push a new VC, with hidden navigation bar it changes color, and works fine when navigation bar is enabled.

A Wrong result: (when `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;`)

[image: Wrong results, status bar translucent and has white color]

This is what I get, but navigation bar is not hidden :

[image: Correct results,but with navigation bar visible, status bar has black color]

I don't get why actually, the presence of navigation bar influence on color(style ) of status bar.

How to make status bar black on iOS7(8), when VC is displayed(pushed onto navigation stack) with hidden navigation bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view, put it where the status bar will be, and set its background color to which ever color you require. For example:

```
UIView *statusBarView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                        [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.width,
                        [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height)];
statusBarView.backgroundColor  =  [UIColor blackColor]; // Set color
[self.view addSubview:statusBarView];
```

Comment: thx Daniel, Indeed, addition of translucent view solved, my issue. However, Instead of hard-coding size, it is better to refer to status bar properties.